# Importing and visualizing pictures in racket without using DrRacket

Tags: image, lisp, racket

How can import and an `.png` image and use it for some animation pragmatically **without** using `Insert > Insert Image...` option in **DrRacket** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on which image library you're using.

If you are using the [2htdp](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html) image library, use [`bitmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28form._%28%28lib._2htdp/image..rkt%29._bitmap%29%29) or [`bitmap/url`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp/image..rkt%29._bitmap/url%29%29). For example, if you have a file named "plane.png" saved in the same directory as your program, write something like

```
(define plane-image (bitmap "plane.png"))
```

If you are using the [pict](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/) library (eg with slideshow), use its [`bitmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pict/Basic_Pict_Constructors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._pict%2Fmain..rkt%29._bitmap%29%29) function. If you are using the basic drawing library (racket/draw), then create an instance of the [`bitmap%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/bitmap_.html) class.